# Counting distinct id from xml node list and storing back in a variable under XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following xml list

```
<policyList>
<policy policyID="1"/>
<policy policyID="1"/>
<policy policyID="2"/>
<policy policyID="2"/>
<policy policyID="3"/>
</policyList>
```

my requirement is to count the distinct policyID in xslt 1.0 and store it in a variable so that we can use it in my other template.

Please provide your thoughts on this. it would be great appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Well, what framework/language are you calling this from?

Comment: I'm using ..net framework 4.5 and language C#.

Answer (score 1):

Use a key and count the number of "groups" that key gives, see http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2Cb. There I have defined the key

```
<xsl:key name="by-id" match="policy" use="@policyID"/>
```

and then the variable simply does

```
<xsl:variable name="count" select="count(//policy[generate-id() = generate-id(key('by-id', @policyID)[1])])"/>
```

For your sample the output is `3`. Read up on [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml) to understand more about that use of keys in XSLT 1.0.